# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp due to taglib

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I create a jsp project with idea 2016 and the code of jsf is as following.

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title>JSP 2.0 Expression Language - Implicit Objects</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JSP 2.0 Expression Language - Implicit Objects</h1>
<hr>
This example illustrates some of the implicit objects available
in the Expression Language.  The following implicit objects are
available (not all illustrated here):
<ul>
  <li>pageContext - the PageContext object</li>
  <li>pageScope - a Map that maps page-scoped attribute names to
    their values</li>
  <li>requestScope - a Map that maps request-scoped attribute names
    to their values</li>
  <li>sessionScope - a Map that maps session-scoped attribute names
    to their values</li>
  <li>applicationScope - a Map that maps application-scoped attribute
    names to their values</li>
  <li>param - a Map that maps parameter names to a single String
    parameter value</li>
  <li>paramValues - a Map that maps parameter names to a String[] of
    all values for that parameter</li>
  <li>header - a Map that maps header names to a single String
    header value</li>
  <li>headerValues - a Map that maps header names to a String[] of
    all values for that header</li>
  <li>initParam - a Map that maps context initialization parameter
    names to their String parameter value</li>
  <li>cookie - a Map that maps cookie names to a single Cookie object.</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I got following error info.

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.69 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
```

After I remove below line, the exception disappears.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

I downloaded jstl-1.2.jar and added it into external libraries of my project. The issue is still there. Anybody knows how to handle or debug the issue?

Comment: i am not sure which JAR file you need, but you need to make sure it's placed in `web-inf/lib` dir of your website

Comment: Did you [add the jars to the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) you deploy on the server?

Answer (score 8):

Finally I resolved the issue by myself. Below are steps:

1.Download jstl-1.2.jar and standard-1.1.2.jar from below links.

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/

2.Copy the two files into Tomcat lib folder.

3.Rename standard-1.1.2.jar to standard.jar.

The exception disappears then.